# EF Core 5 filter in memory list based on entity property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I want to perform a query like this, but cannot be translated:

```
var toCheckSimilarSongs = new List<string>() { "Highway to hell", "Nothing else matters" };
var similarSongs = Context.ReadSet<Song>()
    .Select(song => new
    {
          Name = song.Name,
          ToCheckSimilarSong = toCheckSimilarSongs
              .FirstOrDefault(toCheckSimilarSong => song.Name.Contains(toCheckSimilarSong))  
    });
```

The idea is that I want to have a list of song names with similar song (to perform group by later etc). Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible with EF Core. It supports only `Contains` with local collections and very simple `Any`.

Comment: What is this query trying to do? Sending a bunch of lookup data to do a simple mapping wouldn't work that well even if EF Core could do it. It would be a different story if the lookup data was already in the database. Databases have google-like foll text search capabilities that are completely different (and faster) than a `LIKE '%blah%'`. In SQL Server you can use a Full-Text-Search index and eg `CONTAINS` or `FREETEXT` to find rows that come close to a phrase with ranking

Comment: FREETEXT I am trying to do, but my problem is my in memory collection. I want to obtain a list of song names with corresponding item from local array

Comment: Maybe your in-memory collection came from database?

Comment: Nope, come from frontend. I want to see for my frontend names similars songs from database and tie together